# How to run a .batch file as if it were a .bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Context: I have associated `.batch` extension to be opened by my text editor by default when double-clicking or hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on it in the Explorer (default action for "Open").

(I probably can't do this directly for `.bat` files and it's probably not something we want, it could break other things).

Example:

```
helloworld.batch
================
dir
md hello
cd hello
```

**How to run this file from command line as if it were a .bat or .cmd?**

Doing `call helloworld.batch` opens it in my editor, doing `helloworld.batch` in the command line does the same; idem for `start helloworld.batch`. **How to actually run it?**

---

PS: why do I want to achieve this? Let's compare these situations:

- Before: Double click on `test.bat`, run it. Oh no it hasn't worked as expected, and the window is now closed and I haven't seen the error (it went too fast)... I should have added `pause` at the end. Let's open it in the text editor. I edit it. I save, I close the editor. Let's double click on `test.bat` again...
- After: Double-click on `test.batch`, it opens in the text editor. `CTRL+B`, it runs and I see the output in the bottom panel of my editor. If there's something to copy/paste, I can (not possible in `cmd.exe` by default even if I found a way). If there's something to modify in the batch I'm already in the editor... Life is good :) –

Comment: Have you tried `Start helloworld.batch`?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes it's the same than `call`.

Comment: note that you usually run a batch file more often than you write it, so it makes more sense to set the default action to execute instead of exit

Comment: @phuclv In my case, I rarely execute a .bat or .batch from Explorer, I always open it in the text editor and CTRL+B to run it, and have the console display the results.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
cmd < file.batch
```

(An end-of-line is required at the end of the last text-line in the file.)

Comment: I can't for the life of me understand what the OP is trying to achieve: a .bat or .batch file is a command file, it's meant to execute commands in CLI, not to have its content displayed in a text editor. You can always right-click on it and modify it if you don't get the results you expected, but once you get it to work properly, why bother to open it in a text editor and press Ctrl-B, wait for it to execute, then close the CLI window, THEN the text editor's? I must be missing something..

Comment: @Didier: I would guess he is using `.batch` while developing the script, then renaming to `.bat` when finished.

Comment: @Didier I added the reason at the end of my question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but a .bat file is supposed to be *run*, period. If you are going to develop using .bat files, do so, it's no skin off my back, but that's not the purpose of a .bat script in the first place. Once your script is done just so, and running to your satisfaction, you "should" (again, you do what you want) just run it, not open it in a text editor then run it with Ctrl-B, then close both the CLI and text editor windows. It's a waste of time, plus some formatting issues can come in the way when you do that. Same as with AppleScript: write it, test it, run it, forget it.

Comment: @Didier: Such discussions shouldn't be here. Anyway, the poster has his own tools and methods.

Comment: Agreed, but when you accidentally add a space at the end of a line, and try to run a script from the text editor, and get an error in the CLI that you wouldn't otherwise get if you had saved your script, *then* run it from CLI as it's meant to be, you tend to rethink your "tools and methods". Been there, done that. And that's for simple scripts. Imagine when you've got one that's several dozens lines long, with gotos and loops/for all over the place...

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for your answer. It works from command line: `cmd < test.batch`, but when running from inside the text editor (it uses Python `subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "<", "test.batch"])` internally I think), it does not work; it's not a problem of path, the file is detected but nothing is run.

Comment: An example for Python : See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417010/subprocess-popen-stdin-read-file).